# How to enable a button only if the both image view and textfield are not nil?

Tags: swift, imageview, textfield

I am trying to make the button enabled only if the imageview and textfield both are not empty. However, the button doesn't become enabled at all.

In the viewLoad method, I disabled the button `postBtn`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.postBtn.isEnabled = false
}
```

in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method:

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
...
    if (imageView.image == nil || postText.text?.isEmpty ?? true){
//if any nil don't pose
            print("do not")
            self.postBtn.isEnabled = false

       } else {
         print("post")
        self.postBtn.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: Have you added IBAction for postBtn?

Comment: What happens when this code is run? Also note that you need to update the `isEnabled` each time the text in the text field changes.

Comment: @rmaddy the button stays disabled and doesn't appear. Yes, I will add that after this works.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes, postBtn is already there.

Comment: @AliDeV _"doesn't appear"_ means it is hidden not disabled. Try        self.postBtn.isEnabled = true and self.postBtn.isHidden = false

Comment: @AliDeV Have you added action for the button?

Comment: @AliDeV I'm asking what the code you posted actually does. In the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, what happens with that `if` statement? Which `print` do you see? Are you doing this after you update `imageView.image`? And does the text field actually have text?

Comment: @AliDeV Also, you state the button doesn't appear. If it doesn't appear, then how do you know it is disabled?

Comment: @rmaddy I meant disabled not hidden. Anyway, after adding the BeginEditing method, the problem fixed. Thank for suggesting that.